# Export dates to Javascript format

Tags: javascript, vba, date, formatting

How can I export/convert a regular date (dd/mm/yyyy or whatever other format) format from Excel to a JavaScript date format which looks like this:
1136005200000 (for 31/12/2005).
Thanks!

Comment: Are you planning to do the work on the Excel side or JavaScript side?

Comment: I have some data in Excel which I export to an .xml file that I read with JavaScript

Comment: In Excel I have a list with dates and values... which I export to an xml file.. than I want to push the data in JavaScript and use it with http://nvd3.com/ghpages/linePlusBar.html framework (see the example ...you have the date in JS format and the value) I want to convert a regular date from Excel to a date in JS format.

Comment: JS can handle dates in string form. I believe however you might need to change your date format to mm/dd/yyyy for js to read it. But `new Date('12/31/2005')` will work.

Comment: Subtract the date "1/1/1970" to get the number of days, and then multiply by 24*60*60*1000 to convert to milliseconds.

Comment: thanks tim... this helps a lot... I didnlt know how js date format is generated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Function Tester()
    Dim sc As Object, o As Object
    Set sc = CreateObject("ScriptControl")
    sc.Language = "JScript"
    Debug.Print sc.Eval("new Date('12/31/2005')*1")
End Function
```